# While loop is not stopping when condition is met

Tags: c, while-loop

I have a while loop that lets the user input any amount of numbers separated by white space, and the program is supposed to terminated while showing the the highest number to the user, when the user inputs a `0`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  float fResult[100], fMax;
  int c = 1;
  while (fResult[c] != 0){
    scanf(" %f ", &fResult[c]);
    if (fResult[c] > fMax){
        fMax = fResult[c];
    }
    c = c + 1;
  }
  if (fResult[1]==0){
    printf("empty sequence");
  } else {
    printf("%.3f ", fMax);
  }
}
```

It works fine until the user inputs a sequence of nothing but negative numbers. Then the result is showing as `0`.

For example, when the user inputs `-3 -4 -100 -5 0`, the result should be `-3`, but instead I get a `0`, which is technically the maximum number.
But isn't the while loop supposed to be ignored if the user inputs a `0`?

Comment: You never check whether `scanf` actually succeeds.

Comment: `while (fResult[c] != 0)` you haven't input any data into `fResult`

Comment: You havent initialized fMax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intialize `fMax` to the first value read. No need to save the values in an array. Always check `scanf()`'s return value.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    float f, fMax;

    if (scanf("%f", &fMax) != 1) {
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if (fMax == 0.0) {
        (void) printf("empty sequence\n");
    } else {
        for (;;) {
            if (scanf("%f", &f) != 1) {
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            if (f == 0.0) {
                break;
            }
            if (f > fMax) {
                fMax = f;
            }
        }
        (void) printf("%.3f\n", fMax);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here your are taking input first then after comparing and assigning to `fMax` you are checking `while` loop condition that's the reason.

initialize `fMax` and `fResult[1]` before comparison and also check `c` is not greater tha 100 to avoid array index out of bounds arror.

Answer (score 0):

**Simply a case of undefined behaviour:**

`fmax` is accidently zero, upon left uninitialized. *Automatic variable when left uninitialized can have any garbage value.* It is zero in your case. So in first four iterations, `fmax` would have stayed at zero value upon comparison with negative values.

You should follow the principle: **populate first - then access**